# Obtener informacion de un nodo en firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

Como puedo extraer solo la información del nodo que yo seleccione en firebase
EJEMPLO:

- `-L-qKQ-UICkQ1K-QAJDx`
- `name: 'Jesus'`
- `-L-qKRq1_yZmTdjvRqfN`
- `name: 'Moises'`

Deseo solo extraer el nodo `'-L-qKRq1_yZmTdjvRqfN'` donde se encuentra el name 'Moises'

Existe alguna forma sin tener que seleccionar todos ?

```
firebase.database().ref('usuarios').on('value', function(data) {
    var element = data.val();
    $.each(element, function(nodo, value) {
        if(nodo == '-L-qKRq1_yZmTdjvRqfN') console.log(value.name);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer eso usando la función [equalTo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Query#equalTo)

```
firebase.database().ref('usuarios').orderByChild('name').equalTo('Moises').on('child_added', function(data) {
    var element = data.val();
    console.log(element.name);
});
```

Ten en cuenta que sólo puedes usar una condición (no puedes poner 2 `equalTo` en una misma consulta).

Comment: Gracias es lo que buscaba.